# Is there any point in creating a custom iterator for an array in node.js?

Tags: javascript, iterator

I need to parse an 80GB+ CSV file, and thought this a good opportunity to understand iterators in JavaScript (and then probably use an existing library such as [csv-iterator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-iterator), [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv), etc).

Looking at an iterator example on MDN [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), I see this code:

```
function makeIterator(array) {
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function() {
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    };
}
```

Which is pretty self-explanatory. I can create an iterator for an array:

```
var iteratorForMyArray = makeIterator([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, etc])
```

And then I can use my shiny new iterator to 'iteratively' pull out values of my array:

```
var val0 = iteratorForMyArray.next().value
var val1 = iteratorForMyArray.next().value
etc
```

I can see why this is useful when parsing a CSV file. I'm wondering if there is any point in creating such an iterator for a simple array?

I often find that while simplified examples are useful for understanding, it's sometimes hard to see when the example is only useful as an example vs is actually useful in programming.

Because JavaScript already provides 2 mechanisms for creating iterators over array structures:

***1: Basic `for` loop***

```
for (let i = 0, i < [1,2,3,4,etc]; i++) {
  ...
}
```

***2: Array.prototype.forEach***

```
[1,2,3,4,etc].forEach(function(val, i, arr) {
  ...
})
```

(which I have just seen is slow on [this](https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead) site)

***Questions:***

1. Does my custom iterator offer anything that these iterators don't?
2. Do both these 'in-house' iterators create 'iterators' (i.e. what I understand as sequential pointers to values in data structures)? Or am I off by miles...

Comment: You mention `.forEach()` being slow, but that's because it calls a function on each iteration, which your custom iterator does too. Anyway, if your intention is to iterate over the whole array at once, like a `for` loop or `.forEach()` then there's no point to a custom iterator, it's just going to make your code harder to read. If your intention is to be able to iterate over it gradually, as in, say, grabbing the next element or two in response to some async event, or from more than one place in your code, *then* a custom iterator could be useful to keep track of which element you're up to.

Comment: There are other ways of slowing down loop iteration that don't involve custom iterators though, and that would also probably be easy to read (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good feature of iterators is that each call gets the next element, whereas *forEach* it's all or nothing (you can't exit early), and with both a *for* loop and *forEach* all the logic must be inside the loop.

Consider an array iterator like:

```js
function arrayIterator(array) {
  
  // Get array indexes as an array
  var indexes = Object.keys(array)
    .filter(
      // Test for valid Array index property
      key => key == +key && key >= 0 && key.length == String(+key).length)
    // Sort as numbers
    .sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

  // Parameters held in closure
  var current = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var maxCount = indexes.length;

  // Return iterator function
  return function() {
    return ++count > maxCount? 'done' : array[indexes[current++]];
  };
}

var arr = [0,1,,,4,5,6];

// Add non-index numeric property
arr['01'] = '01';
// Add indexable numeric property
arr['10'] = '10';
// Add some other property
arr.foo = 'foo';

var x = arrayIterator(arr);
console.log(x()); // 0
console.log(x()); // 1
console.log(x()); // 4
console.log(x()); // 5
console.log(x()); // 6
console.log(x()); // 10
console.log(x()); // 'done'
console.log(x()); // 'done'
```

I'm sure there's more to be done in regard to checking valid indexes and also testing that an index still exists when the iterator is called, but is shows the concept.

There also needs to be some documentation about what happens when the array is modified between calls.

Answer (score 2):

ForEach guarantees order, as well as it'll skip invalid indexes etc. Your iterator doesn't provide anything extra when compared to a standard for loop, it'll just be slower, as you're calling a function to get the next item, where a basic for loop doesn't have this overhead. Use a for loop and cache the length to start for better performance.

Comment: It's pretty easy to have an Array iterator that does both those things without the restrictions of *forEach*.